# What happens to Angel Dust at the end of the Deadpool movie?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool-2016

The movie shows that Colossus carries Negasonic and Angel Dust to safety when the junkyard structure collapses but Angel Dust isn't shown anymore after Ajax/Francis is killed. Is there any information on what happens to her? I'm curious because the movie hints at some form of goodwill (if you can call it that) developing between her and Colossus during the fight.

Comment: Of all the characters I'd hope *not* to develop sexual tension, it'd be those two.

Comment: @Valorum I ship them. May they have many mega-strong chrome babies.

Comment: The wiki is no help. It merely speculates that she was turned in to the authorities; http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/Angel_Dust

Comment: She immediately took advantage of his chivalry and hit him in the balls, I wouldn't call that "Goodwill".

Comment: Wait for Deadpool 2...

Comment: Well, considering that she didn't appear in Deadpool 2, it does seem most likely that she was turned into the authorities.